# Google Push Notification not reliable, many messages not sent

Tags: android, push-notification

I have been using android GCM and there is a lot of problem regarding push messages not sent. What alternative should I use to have more reliable push notification service on android?

Comment: You can try *pull* method. Make your app, pull the data at particular intervals.

Comment: google itself has introduced new and better alternative https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: @Prerak Sola, can you please show me example or link to use this pull method?

Comment: Please consider https://pushy.me, an alternative to GCM/FCM which greatly improves notification speed & reliability (Full disclosure - I founded Pushy).